# How do I add a reset button in a counter?

Tags: javascript

There are three buttons which the user can click to increment, decrement, or reset the number (which is 0 at default). I attempted to make a reset button that seemed to work because the number was set to 0, but if I clicked the increment or decrement button, it adds/subtracts and displays the number before it was reset.

```js
   let number = 0;
   function increment() {
       number++;
       document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
   }
   function decrement() {
       number--;
       document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
   }
   function reset() {
       let number = 0;
       document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
   }
```

```html
<span id="number"></span>
<button id="increment" onclick="increment()">Increment</button>
<button id="decrement" onclick="decrement()">Decrement</button>
<button id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Be sure to flag any of the answers if it solved your problem. This makes it easier for others to find solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Inside reset change `let number = 0;` with `number = 0;`

```html
  <button id="increment" onclick="increment()">Increment</button>
    <button id="decrement" onclick="decrement()">Decrement</button>
    <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
    <p id='number'></p>

    <script>
    let number = 0;
    function increment() {
        number++;
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
    }
    function decrement() {
        number--;
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
    }
    function reset() {
        number = 0;
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

By adding `let` inside your function you are creating another (local) variable called `number` instead of changing the already existing, global variable. Just leave it out to access the original variable:

```
function reset() {
    number = 0;
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
}
```

As a side note: javascript already has a function called `Number`, so it is best to not use such a similar name for your variable, like `count`, or something a bit more descriptive like `amount_of_something`.

Answer (score -1):

Besides the `let` typo in your code

- Don't use IDs. Code should be reusable. Create a more flexible code for the sake of DRY. The below example can be used on any number of such UI elements. Just wrap them inside a common parent element and use Class
- Don't use unsafe inline `on*` handlers attributes. JS should be in one place only. Use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.
- Use `type="button"` on button elements that are willingly not of type Submit (default)
- Instead of a `<span>` use an `<input type="number">` element, and eventually add the `readonly` attribute.
- Use the Input's JS `stepUp()` and `stepDown()` native methods

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);


// Number inputs with arrows:

const initInputArrows = (elNum) => {
  const elUp = el(".num-up", elNum);
  const elDn = el(".num-down", elNum);
  const elRs = el(".num-reset", elNum);
  const elIn = el(".num-input", elNum);
  elDn.addEventListener("pointerdown", () => elIn.stepDown());
  elUp.addEventListener("pointerdown", () => elIn.stepUp());
  elRs.addEventListener("pointerdown", () => elIn.value = 0);
};

els(".num").forEach(initInputArrows);
```

```html
<div class="num">
  <input type="number" class="num-input" min=0 max=100 step=1 value=0>
  <button type="button" class="num-up">&#x25B4;</button>
  <button type="button" class="num-down">&#x25BE;</button>
  <button type="button" class="num-reset">&#x00D7;</button>
</div>

<div class="num">
  <input type="number" class="num-input" min=0 max=100 step=0.5 value=5.5>
  <button type="button" class="num-up">&#x25B4;</button>
  <button type="button" class="num-down">&#x25BE;</button>
  <button type="button" class="num-reset">&#x00D7;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of this code bloat, use delegation

Comment: @mplungjan there's absolutely no need to use delegation when you can ***Init***. (Create an example of the above that uses delegation. Then ask yourself which one has code smell). Delegation (in the above) makes no sense firstly because there's no static parent element reference and can suffer from unnecessarily querying the DOM instead of attaching **immediately** the listeners, no need to traverse and no unnecessary statements. Delegation has its superb benefits and uses. BTW, I've seen recently, you started to overuse delegation unnecessarily. Be wise

Comment: That is an opinion. If I have a group of things to click that act on the same variable and output to the same field the I will WRAP them in a static container and delegate - makes for compact and readable code as you can see in my deleted answer. Even you have a div wrapping the buttons and output

Comment: @mplungjan Ah, yes, I see it. After a first look, I think it's a good thing you deleted it (though I don't understand why you attracted 4 downvotes - that's odd).  Why no `else if`? To many roundtrip statements. And why enter a function handler at all if there's no need to call it? To bloat the call stack? Also there's no need to trigger a default `number.textContent = num;` action - which you're doing. I understand your opinion dear mplungjan. Delegation is OK-*ish* but unnecessary code smell in such case.

Comment: Why would there not be a need to convert the string to a number before adding to it? I can move the + to the add statement, but that is not so obvious

Comment: Also why even have the buttons when type="number" has spinners? You change OP's base fields to match your implementation

Comment: @mplungjan Exactly, thank you for the default spinners nuisance notice, one can remove them using CSS or even readonly (if I'm not mistaken) as said in answer. Using input type number is indeed an intentional suggestion with minimal markup changes. Just sharing one of the many ways on how to implement such a UI the way I find would be best and easiest.